# Variable 'data' implicitly has type 'any[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a few type errors in the below function and I'm relatively new to  Typescript and i'm unsure of how to resolve them.

```
private fetchFromUrl = () => {
    var data = []

    fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/tempData/monthly.csv`)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => readString(res))
        .then(res =>{
            const Coords = res.data    
            Coords.forEach(x => data.push( {x: new Date(x[0]), y: Number(x[1]) } ))
        })
        
    return(data)
}
```

The main error complains about **data** having type any[], however when I specify it's type.

```
let data: [Date, number];
```

I get a different error:

```
Argument of type '{ x: Date; y: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | Date'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type 'Date'.
```

I do feel that some of these errors may stem from the error:

```
Object is of type 'unknown'
```

That is present on the x in my foreach.

How would I go about resolving these errors?

Comment: The type `[Date, number]` means an array of length 2 where the first component is a `Date` and the second is a `number`. That does not seem to be what your array is going to be.

Comment: you would be correct, its supposed to be an array of Date, number pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the return value to an array with a date and a number, but you are trying to push an object with properties named `x` (with a Date value) and property `y` (with a number value), so all you need to do is change the typing to:
`let data: [{ x: Date; y: number }]`

Edit: complete answer based on extra question from comments, as `(x)` was also showing untyped:

```
private fetchFromUrl = () => {
    let data: [{ x: Date; y: number }]

    fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/tempData/monthly.csv`)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => readString(res))
        .then(res =>{
            const Coords: [string[]] = res.data    
            Coords.forEach(x => data.push( {x: new Date(x[0]), y: Number(x[1]) } ))
        })
        
    return(data)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've made a change that is very similar but also includes the initialization of the array as well. 

I dont suppose you know what might be causing the object type unknown on the x variable within the foreach?

Comment: any time you get a "unknown" or "implicit any" it usually indicates a *missing* type, in this case typescript can't infer by itself the value of x because Coords is being set as res.data from the api response. so you want to type that too, if you know that its going to be what looks like an array of string arrays? I'd type it as such e.g. const Coords: [string[]] = res.data; and it'll correctly infer the type of x, or you can just directly type (x: [string, string])... this is assuming that the values from your api is strings as its from a csv and you're type casting to number im just guessing

Comment: @DamianJacobs I updated the answer to give you a complete reference for it - Hope it helped :)

Comment: I have other issues surrounding the typing of the papaparse package Im using to convert the csv string to JSON but ultimately this is just for test data until the API for the real data is built and spending more time trying to fix that isn't worth it.

Your answer was spot on though and I learnt a ton from it, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @DamianJacobs no problem, its my pleasure! regarding your comment on paraparse have you tried installing the types for that package? they seem to have an npm package for it e.g. `npm i @types/papaparse` or `yarn add @types/papaparse`

Comment: I did install it but the issue has remained.